# jquery scroll to form input

Tags: jquery, scrollto, scrolltop, jquery-scrollable

I'm attempting a `scrollTo()` on a webpage and I want a button to trigger the `scrollTo()`; it will scroll to the top of the form and highlight the first input field.

My current code works, however the screen quickly flashes. I attempted to use a `preventDefault()` to no avail. Please see my code below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#get-started").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#get-risk").offset().top
        }, 2000);
        $("#get-started-apply-now-form [name='last_name']").focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of using `.animate()`, could you just use `.scrollTo()`? http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When focusing an element, the browser scrolls to that element, messing up your animation.

Place the focus in the animations callback to avoid it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#get-started").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#get-risk").offset().top
        }, 2000, function() {
            $("#get-started-apply-now-form [name='last_name']").focus();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks adeneo! by placing the focus in the animations callback it works great!